# Using thumb picks instead of nails

Tags: electric-guitar, picks

I'm wondering if it is possible to use thumb picks instead of nails. My fingers take a fair bit of punishment when finger picking on the electric and I'm wondering if there can be some sort of plectrum setup you can use to use finger picking / classical style techniques but not put your actual fingers through those thick steel strings?

I basically want to do a Freddy Kruger impression with my picks.

Comment: A friend of mine used clear nail polish on his nails to strengthen them a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of [finger picks available, in metal and plastic](http://www.jimdunlop.com/products/guitar-picks?gclid=Cj0KEQjw_YKtBRC7zZjFp8bF_foBEiQAfyigc_TD3tSihYGSb6hhmv3uknK1EL1Z8V5FL5VGZQqBvL0aArwM8P8HAQ). These picks are so long that the technique (hand/finger motions) involved is different from what you get with your fingers, let alone that the tone is significantly different.  For me, metal picks on electric guitar was unacceptable.

[Alaska Pik](http://www.alaskapik.com/) provides an option that is closer to just extending your nails and may provide a feel and tone closer to natural finger nails.

Artificial nail extensions from a beauty salon may also be useful to extend and strengthen your nails.